# Perplexing Project Management question

Tags: content-type, page-layout

Building a new project management(PM) subsite. the PM team has requested a site template since they pretty much keep building the same functionality over and over again with each new project.

However, management is against the idea of building a ton of subsites and is looking for a solution to minimize this. My idea is as follows:

Single PM site
Custom publishing page layout (content type)
shared libraries and lists

The one site would contain centralized libs and lists with content related to all projects (plans, minutes, etc). A new Page would be created each time a new project is kicked off. The page would include a view of these libs and lists pulling relevant project files based on metadata entered during the upload process.

Pros
One site
Centrally located documents/lists/calendar etc.
easy to create

Cons
Many pages eventually
?

How would someone go about doing this though? Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having a single page with a parameter for whichever project you want to see details of?  You will need a metadata column on your lists and libraries to capture the project but I am guessing you would do this anyway.  You then create your page with the web parts as usual but filter the web part to only show content for the specific project.  If you use CQWP then you can filter by [PageQueryString: Project], if you use LVWP then you can add a parameter and filter to each web part using SPD.

EDIT: Added example XSLT link for clarification.

```
<a href="/SitePages/ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectID={@ID}">
 <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
</a>
```

If you need more clues on XSLT then I have a few posts on my blog which will walk you through it http://paylord.wordpress.com

Comment: That's great for a 'home page' like rollup with options to view each project. I like that. But what would be the best way to architect the site? Use subsites (management frowning), or publishing page layout for each project?

Comment: Your landing page would be a way of selecting which project you want to look at - a navigation page.  You could also combine this with a dashboard-type display to summarise the performance of each project.  When a user clicks on a project to view it you then link to one other page eg ProjectView.aspx?ProjectID=1.  The ProjectID will be unique for each project and allow the web parts on the page to filter and only show content for that project.  So you only have a single site, a landing page and your ProjectView page plus whatever lists and libraries you need.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Just filter everything based on selected project. Very nice. I'm on the cusp of being a developer. How much of this can be done without code? Am I just connecting webparts via "insert form webpart" control? How do I pull each id for the lookup string?

Thanks Dave. This has helped quite a bit.

Comment: I am no developer so  you should be fine :). I usually do links using XSLT - I will edit an example into my answer above.  If you use Content Query web parts then you simply filter them using the example I gave above.  You do not need to connect them at all.

Comment: Dave, didn't want to leave you hanging. I've been playing with this and it's working well. I modified it slightly to fit my needs, but overall it is a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: That is great news - well done :)